# ¿Cómo agregar un evento selected a p-tableCheckbox?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

Hola a todos tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo agregar un evento que al seleccionar el componente `p-tableCheckbox` me muestre un `Toast success` y cuando se desmarque otro `Toast danger`.

Mi código

```
<p-table [value]="tareas" [columns]="cols" [paginator]="true" [rows]="2" editMode="row" dataKey="idTarea" [(selection)]="tareas2">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3em">
                        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                    </th>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        {{col.header}}
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-tarea let-editing="editing" let-ri="rowIndex">
                <!--let-columns="columns"-->
                <!--<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        {{tarea[col.field]}}
                    </td>-->
                <tr [pEditableRow]="tarea">
                    <td>
                        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="tarea" (selection)="SelectRow(event)"></p-tableCheckbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{tarea.idTarea}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <p-cellEditor>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="tarea.descripcion" required>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                {{tarea.descripcion}}
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-cellEditor>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" class="ui-button-info" (click)="onRowEditInit(tarea)"></button>
                        <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" class="ui-button-success" style="margin-right: .5em" (click)="onRowEditSave(tarea)"></button>
                        <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger"></button> &nbsp;
                        <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-trash" class="ui-button-info" (click)="onRowDelete(tarea.idTarea)"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let tarea of tareas2" style="text-align: left">
                        {{tarea.idTarea + ' - ' + tarea.descripcion + ' - ' + tarea.estado}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

Mi método que deseo hacer

```
  SelectRow(checkValue){
      if(checkValue){
        this.messageService.add({severity:'success',summary:'Estado',detail:'Tarea Finalizada.'})
      }else{
        this.messageService.add({severity:'warning',summary:'Estado',detail:'Tarea Pendiente.'})
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente ejemplo. Por defecto tu elemento no se puede visualizar (display: none;), al clicar sobre el cuadrado del check puedes verlo. Solo con HTML y estilo CSS.

```css
/*CSS*/
    .toast {
    display: none;
    }

    .checkbox:checked ~ .toast { display: block; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
     <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="checkbox" value="first_checkbox" hidden/><label htmlFor="check"> Este es mi primer checkbox</label><br>
     
     <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
        <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        Hello, world! This is a toast message.
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta debe basarse a angular primeng.